# Does anyone knows Penis enlargement mantra

Tags: vedas, mantras, atharva-veda

While reading some book i came to know that there is a mantra for penis enlargement. Author said it's a simple sidhi used to do gajakarmana from penis.

Comment: Although not much well known at all among masses, there are even such mantras in scriptures.

Comment: Also plz post for how to get slightly bigger boobz :P Learn something new every day. This is astounding to me. All those guys selling supplements, vitamins, procedures, exercises, equipments for such stuffs, and turns out there is totally different method for this not involving any of those :D

Comment: It’s still making me laugh that this is an actual topic post on here :D Once I’m able to read and translate Tantras texts properly I will post more info if I find it :)